# Problemas con el Insert

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Buenas estamos gestionando un ingreso de datos en una tabla

```
create table UsuariosPorPerfiles ( --SE CREA LA TABLA DE LA BASE A UTILIZAR
    CodigoPerfil int,
    IdentificacionUsuarios int
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UsuariosxPerfiles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    CodigoPerfil,
    IdentificacionUsuarios
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
)ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--LIGUE ENTRE TABLAS, USUARIO Y PERFIL
ALTER TABLE UsuariosPorPerfiles 
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UsuariosxPerfiles_Usuarios] 
FOREIGN KEY (IdentificacionUsuarios)
REFERENCES Usuarios ([IdentificacionUsuarios])

ALTER TABLE UsuariosPorPerfiles 
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UsuariosxPerfiles_CodigoPerfil] 
FOREIGN KEY (CodigoPerfil)
REFERENCES Perfiles ([CodigoPerfil])

INSERT UsuariosPorPerfiles (CodigoPerfil,IdentificacionUsuarios) 
VALUES (1, 402420914)
SELECT * FROM UsuariosPorPerfiles
```

Pero al realizar la inserccion nos da problemas 
nos dice 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya te aseguraste que los codigos que estas insertando, existan en cada una en las tablas a las que hace referencia las llaves foraneas? Es decir, que en la tabla Perfiles y en la usuarios esten los codigos 1 y 402420914 respectivamente?

Comment: Me parece que el error viene, porque no tenes el registro en la otra tabla, a la que haces referencia, te falta el registro en identificacionUsuarios

Answer (score 1):

El problema te sucede porque tienes una relación de llave foranea llamada `FK_UsuariosxPerfiles_Usuarios` entre la Tabla `UsuariosPorPerfiles` y `Usuarios`.

Para poder insertar en la tabla `UsuariosPorPerfiles` debes primero tener un registro en la tabla `Usuarios`, donde el valor que tenga en la columna `IdentificacionUsuarios` sea el mismo que intentas insertar en la columna `IdentificacionUsuarios` de la tabla `UsuariosPorPerfiles`.

Answer (score 0):

El error que te da es porque tienes definida una relación entre las tablas `UsuariosxPerfiles` y `Usuarios`.

Posiblemente en la sentencia `INSERT` estás intentando introducir un registro en `UsuariosxPerfiles` que no cumple con la integridad referencial, bien porque el código de perfil 1 no existe en la tabla relacionada (posiblemente `Perfiles`) o bien porque el código de usuario 402420914 no existe en la tabla de `Usuarios`

Por el error que te da sobre la restricción `FK_UsuariosxPerfiles_Usuarios`, lo más posible es que el error sea que no existe el código de usuario

Comment: Buenas excelente, si tuvimos que volver a revisar las sentencias y los parametros, logramos corregirlo, apenas pueda lo comparto